# How can we replace a interface method in groovy?

Tags: groovy

## Question

How can I overwrite a method in Groovy if the class implements an interface?  If the class does not implement an interface I can overwrite the method, but if the class implements an interface the method does not overwrite.

#### Example without implement

```
interface IA {
    void abc()
}

class A {
    void abc()  {
        println "original"
    }
}

x= new A()
x.abc()
x.metaClass.abc = {-> println "new" }
x.abc()
```

The output of this is

```
original
new
```

### Example with implement

> Consider the following example where class A implements interface IA

```
interface IA {
    void abc()
}

class A implements IA {
    void abc()  {
        println "original"
    }
}


x= new A()
x.abc()
x.metaClass.abc = {-> println "new" }
x.abc()
```

The output in this case is

```
original
original
```

Comment: x.abc is just call the method of interface IA.

Comment: I deleted my comment and clarified the question

Comment: Think that's this long standing bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3493

Comment: GROOVY-3493 will be fixed in Groovy 4.  Thanks for the link back to the ticket.  https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/55fb428c4f6dfad37be5f752282a97089cb1b5ad

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, looks like this is a pretty embarrassing bug, unfortunately.

But depending on your actual scenario, it may be possible to work around the problem.

### Use Groovy @Category

If you can control where the method will be called, then you can use a Groovy Category to replace the method within a block:

```
x= new A()
x.abc()

@Category(A)
class ReplaceAbc {
    void abc() {
        println 'new'
    }
}

use(ReplaceAbc) {
    x.abc()
}
```

### Replace the instance with an anonymous sub-type of the original type

If you can re-assign the variable, then this is an obvious way to override the method:

```
x= new A()
x.abc()
x = new A() {
    @Override
    void abc() {
        println 'new'
    }
}
x.abc()
```

Comment: "Replace the instance with an anonymous sub-type of the original type" - Be aware that that approach does not replace the interface method.  It defines a new class which extends a class which implements the interface.  The implication is that only instances of that particular subclass will have the new method, not all implementations of `IA`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I overwrite a method in Groovy if the class implements an
> interface?

There are a few ways to do it.  One is with runtime extension methods.

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface).

[lib/src/main/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/IA.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/blob/5cdd6d063e8c948f12a47d95e560d81af068650c/lib/src/main/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/IA.groovy)

```
package victorchoymetaprogramminginterface

interface IA {
    String abc()
}
```

[lib/src/main/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/A.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/blob/5cdd6d063e8c948f12a47d95e560d81af068650c/lib/src/main/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/A.groovy)

```
package victorchoymetaprogramminginterface

class A implements IA{
    @Override
    String abc() {
        'A.abc'
    }
}
```

[lib/src/main/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/extensions/SomeInterfaceExtensionMethods.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/blob/5cdd6d063e8c948f12a47d95e560d81af068650c/lib/src/main/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/extensions/SomeInterfaceExtensionMethods.groovy)

```
package victorchoymetaprogramminginterface.extensions

import victorchoymetaprogramminginterface.IA

class SomeInterfaceExtensionMethods {

    static String abc(IA ia) {
        'SomeInterfaceExtensionMethods.abc'
    }
}
```

[lib/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/blob/5cdd6d063e8c948f12a47d95e560d81af068650c/lib/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule)

```
moduleVersion=1.0
moduleName=Demo Extensions
staticExtensionClasses=victorchoymetaprogramminginterface.extensions.SomeInterfaceExtensionMethods
```

The following test passes:

[lib/src/test/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/TestInterfaceExtensions.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/blob/5cdd6d063e8c948f12a47d95e560d81af068650c/lib/src/test/groovy/victorchoymetaprogramminginterface/TestInterfaceExtensions.groovy)

```
package victorchoymetaprogramminginterface

import spock.lang.Specification

class TestInterfaceExtensions extends Specification {
    def "test interface extensions"() {
        setup:
        def obj = new A()

        expect:
        obj.abc() == 'SomeInterfaceExtensionMethods.abc'
    }
}
```